# Create new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary object fails in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

PowerShell version: 5.x, 6

I'm trying to create a new object of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`, but it fails.

I tried the following "versions":

```
> $dictionary = new-object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string],[int]]
New-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ComObject'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:25
+ ... ry = new-object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string],[int]]
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

> $dictionary = new-object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,int]
New-Object : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ComObject'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:25
+ ... ionary = new-object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,int]
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I know that I can use a hashtable under PowerShell, but I want to know how to create a dictionary via the above declaration.

What am I missing?

Thx

Comment: Escape the `,` _comma_ using backtick as ``new-object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string]`,[int]]``, or using quotes as `new-object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string],[int]]"`

Comment: @JosefZ, thx. It works. Please add your comment as answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Used type name `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string],[int]]` contains a comma. By [Creating and initializing an array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-5.1#creating-and-initializing-an-array):

> To create and initialize an array, assign multiple values to a
>   variable. The values stored in the array are **delimited with a
>   comma**…

Hence, you need to escape the comma (read the [about_Escape_Characters](https://github.com/juanpablojofre/About/blob/master/v3/Topic/about_Escape_Characters.md) and [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1) help topics). There are more options:

> In Windows PowerShell, the escape character is the *backtick* (`` ` ``),
>   also called the *grave accent* (ASCII 96).

```
$dictionary = new-object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string]`,[int]]
```

> Quotation marks are used to specify a literal string. You can enclose
>   a string in *single quotation marks* (`'`) or *double quotation marks*
>   (`"`).

```
$dictionary = new-object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string],[int]]"
```

or

```
$dictionary = new-object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string],[int]]'
```

Answer (score 6):

As well as the accepted answer, a dictionary can also be initialised using the syntax in the code block below, which:

- removes the need to escape any characters
- is much cleaner (in my opinion)
- gives you intellisense (tested in PowerShell & PowerShell ISE)

```
$dictionary = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,int]]::new()
```

... where `string` and `int` are .NET types.

Comment: While this is true now, it wasn't always.  The constructor syntax `::new()` wasn't introduced until PSv5 which is the standard since Server 2016, Windows 8.1

Answer (score 3):

The problem is how [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) is interpreting your argument.

When you include a comma in your string, it's now trying to bind

```
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string]', '[int]]'
```

to the `-TypeName` parameter which is of type `<string[]>` or in the error message, `<System.Object[]>`.  This can be solved by properly quoting your argument so it matches the expected parameter binding of `<string>`:

```
New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[string], [int]]'
```