# Strong typing dictionary contents

Tags: powershell, dictionary, ordereddictionary, strong-typing

As part of a refactor of a large PowerShell program from PS2.0, functions and scripting quick practices to PS5.0, classes and programming best practices, I have been moving to strong typing everywhere and finding some places where that brings up questions. The latest one being hash tables.
With both `[Array]` and `[Hashtable]` you can have a mix of content, which then makes enumerating that collection impossible to strongly type. For Arrays you have options like `[String[]]` or moving to Generic Lists with `[System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]`. But Dictionaries seem to pose a problem. I can't find a way to create a dictionary and limit it's values to a particular type. Something like `[System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary[Int32,Int32]]` fails.
So, IS there a way to make Dictionaries and OrderedDictionaries with strong typing of the index, the value or both? And if there isn't a way, is this considered a bit of a problem that must be overcome, or not a problem and if so why is it not a problem?

Comment: _" I have been moving to strong typing everywhere"_  Why?  PowerShell is designed specifically to be lax with some stuff that other languages are strict on - it is primarily a tool for admins and not for developers, so is more forgiving.  I've been using it since the days of 'monad' and have lost count of the number of scripts I've written and the lack of strong typing has rarely, if ever, been an issue;  you just need to be aware that that's how it works.  Personally, I think you're just creating extra work for yourself for no real gain.

Comment: @boxdog I am using PowerShell for a utility that manages software install, custom,mization, update and uninstall. There's lots of built in features that make it good for such a thing. But the program is thousands of lines of code, not a small script or one-liners, so moving to more "program" best practices helps with extendability, debuting, etc. Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create generic dictionaries, but as per [Create new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary object fails in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857362/create-new-system-collections-generic-dictionary-object-fails-in-powershell) you have to use a backtick to escape the comma in the list of generic type parameters:

e.g.

```
PS> $dict = new-object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int`,string]
```

Note that PowerShell will still do its best to coerce types, so it will only throw an exception if it can't convert the type:

```
PS> $dict.Add("1", "aaa") # equivalent to $dict.Add(1, "aaa")
```

And I don't believe there *is* a generic OrderedDictionary out-of-the-box, which is probably why that fails :-)

```
PS> new-object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary[Int32`,Int32]
New-Object: Cannot find type [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary[Int32,Int32]]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Comment: Interesting. While your `$dict = new-object System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int`,string]` works, I tried the newer constructor approach `$dict = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int`,string]]::new()` and that fails. Bit of a bummer since I really want to be consistent with using the new nomenclature. And `$dict = new-object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary[string`,string]` also fails, I guess suggesting that `Specialized.OrderedDictionary` doesn't follow the same rules?

Comment: @Gordon, when calling the constructor directly, you don't need to escape the comma: `$dict = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int,string]]::new()`. Works for me with PS5 and PS7+.

Comment: Also, on a tangent, what is the escape character for StackOverflow, so I can get a back tick IN a code formatted string, rather than ending it?

Comment: @Gordon Try backslash-escaping the backtick: `\\``

Comment: @Gordon - OrderedDictionary isn't generic so you can't specify type parameters - it's basically "(object, object)" - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.add?view=net-5.0 - ```New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary```

Comment: @zett42 Interesting. An OrderedDictionary is not working for me in PS5.1, throwing `Unable to find type [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary[string,string]].` But a regular dictionary does.

Comment: @Gordon - yep, there is no generic ```System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary<TKey, TItem>``` type - it's just a plain old ```System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary``` with an object key and an object item.

Comment: Aha! So only Generics work, which makes sense I guess. And Microsoft being Microsoft they never made a generic ordered dictionary, because reasons. I guess the answer is with ordered dictionaries you type the value when you add a new member, and you just accept that every member can have a different value type and code to check that.

Comment: It does make me wonder, I have been using OrderedDictionary as a queue, where the key is the same of the queued thing, and the value is an instance of my Queueable class. Perhaps I am abusing that a bit and should use a `[System.Collections.Queue]`. The thing is I need to iterate through my queue to do some reference counting. Basically the queue is a list of things to uninstall, which have shared components, so I check to see if the current item is the last thing to use the shared component, and actually uninstall if it is. May need to explore other options I guess.